# Can likelihood be changed when the prior changes?

Tags: bayesian, prior, gamma-distribution, posterior, likelihood

I have a data which follows gamma distribution and want to know the uncertainty of the parameters of this data.

- $\text{Data} \sim \text{Gamma} (\alpha, \beta)$
- Parameters

  $\alpha \sim \text{Gamma} (k_\alpha, \theta_\alpha)$

  $\beta \sim \text{Gamma}(k_\beta, \theta_\beta)$

I used Winbugs (code below).

```
model{
  for (i in 1:N){
     Y[i] ~ dgamma(k, theta)
  }

  k ~ dgamma(0.1, 0.1)
  theta ~ dgamma(0.1, 0.1)
}
```

1. To plot the likelihood I used a uniform prior then divided the posterior by the prior which makes the posterior same as the likelihood. (Figure1)
   [image]
2. Next I changed the prior several times and looked what happens, but the problem is when I plotted the likelihood by dividing the posterior by the prior, likelihood changes which shouldn’t, whenever I change the prior. (Figure 2, 3)

[image]
[image]

Question

Is it possible that the likelihood changes when the prior changes?
Can somebody help me what the problem is?
If the prior is too narrow, is there a possibility that the posterior might be wrong?

Comment: Likelihood is only a function of the model and the data. If those don't change, the likelihood is the same.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am confused about the results. The likelihood shouldn't be changed but it moves when the prior changes.

Comment: Is the posterior a proper distribution? I am wondering if the model evidence is playing a part in this? If the posterior is a proper distribution than for different priors, you have different marginal likelihoods and that should be taken into account to recover the likelihood, perhaps?

Comment: Would you please explain about it in detail? I'm not sure about your explanation since I just started to study bayesian.

Comment: The posterior is given by $P(\theta|D) = \frac{P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}{\int_{\theta}P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}$. So if you change the prior, the denominator (model evidence) will also change. So, it will not be sufficient to divide the posterior by just $P(\theta)$ to get the likelihood back, you also need to keep track of the evidence term.

Comment: Yes I understood. Then how can I plot the likelihood? Another question is in Figure3 when the prior is narrow the posterior is quite different to Figure1 and Figure2. Why is it that?

Comment: The prior has no effect on the likelihood so I suspect you have a bug somewhere. It's likely just due to the randomness of monte carlo but might indicate that your monte carlo chains have not converged. You probably need to run it much longer.

Comment: I just ran 100000 but unfortunately the result is same. Can there be some other reasons?

Comment: To Luca: I understood what you've mentioned about the denominator(model evidence) which changes when the prior changes, but isn't it a constant? I think the denominator can be changed but it affects to the scale of the likelihood not the location of the likelihood. Am I right?

Comment: You should provide your entire code for us. It would help to figure out what's happening. Your current code doesn't have a uniform as a prior. Also, aren't you mixing up joint and marginal priors (posteriors)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For uniform prior I just used duni() rather than dgamma(). k~duni(), theta~duni(). All the other things are same. Can you give me some more explanation about what mixing up joint and marginal priors means? The figures are only for shape parameter. I have the results of scale parameter as well but uploaded only shape parameter.

Comment: I understand that dividing the joint posterior by the joint prior should give the same likelihood (up to a constant). But I'm not sure this is true if you're dividing a marginal posterior over a marginal prior. That was my point.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how you're actually dividing the posterior by the prior. I mean, how do you (your code) exactly do that? It may be a problem with your code that implement this part of your reasoning. That's why I asked for your complete code.

Answer (score 3):

The likelihood expressed in terms of the prior, the posterior and the evidence is:
$$p(D|\alpha,\beta)=\frac{p(\alpha,\beta|D)p(D)}{p(\alpha,\beta)}$$
I assume that what you are looking at is:
$$
p(D) \int p(D|\alpha,\beta) \,\mathrm{d}\beta
= p(D) \int \frac{p(\alpha,\beta|D)p(D)}{p(\alpha,\beta)} \,\mathrm{d}\beta
$$

What you actually should look at is:
$$
\frac{\int p(\alpha,\beta|D)p(D) \,\mathrm{d}\beta}{\int p(\alpha,\beta) \,\mathrm{d}\beta}
=\frac{ p(\alpha|D) p(D)}{p(\alpha)}
= p(D|\alpha)
$$

However, without seeing your complete code, we do not know what you are looking at. What we know for sure is that the Likelihood does not depend on the choice of the prior distribution.